# Dell E7470 Imaging in Windows PE and Acronis

Tags: hard-drive, disk-image, imaging, windows-pe, acronis

Our India office has received a shipment of Dell Latitude E7470 laptops.  Our technician there is having issues imaging this laptop when attempting to use Acronis True Image (2015) as well in Win PE (Version 3 I believe for Windows 7 SP1).  The issue in both cases is that the internal drive doesn't seem to be detected in both WinPE (using diskpart to list drives) or in Acronis (when selecting the destination disk).

For WinPE, I injected USB 3.0 drivers as well as Intel rapid drivers/ssd drivers from Dell's driver section for the laptop -- even injected from Dell's own driver packs which are typically used in MDT/SCCM environments and still no luck detecting the drive.

We have the same model in the U.S. and have not run into any of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Everything I can find points to the fact that the only "Supported" WinPE environment for this hardware is WinPE 10.

[Official Link](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN300689/en)

> #### Requirements
>
> Below are the requirements to install Windows 7 with the m2 SSD.
>
> - "RAID On" enabled in BIOS.
> - "UEFI Boot with Legacy Option ROM enabled" in BIOS.
> - Windows PE 10.0.10586
> - Intel Rapid Storage 14.5.x
> - MDT 2013 Update 1 / SCCM 2012 R2 CU3 running on Server 2012 R2.

It would seem this requirement is based on two factors

- Intel Skylake Chipset
- Samsung NVM storage platform

Comment: Thanks @blaughw - I just came across this as well.  Will give it a shot and let you know the results!